# .htaccess file makes page load indefinitely?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the following `.htaccess` so that pages preceded by `/cn/` load with `http` (the rest loads with `https`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http requests anything other than /cn should become https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule !^cn(/.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,NE]

# https requests for /cn should become http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^cn(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          110M
```

The strange thing is that the page just keeps loading forever. What could be causing this?

Comment: Do you mean redirect loop or the browser is waiting on input from the server forever? Your config also changes the php `upload_max_filesize`... are you uploading large files first with little bandwidth?

Comment: @Andy Jones I think it's a `redirect loop`.